# Fixed footer is cropped by Mobile Safari UI footer

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari

Trying to get my icon footer with social links to move above the Safari UI footer without adding padding or margin that breaks the style of the fixed bar on chrome or other browsers. Not sure why it's happening or if there's even an answer. This issue is when you click my hamburger menu and reveal my personal info it gets cropped at the bottom a bit and doesn't allow for the full size of the footer.

Hope you guys can help.

https://www.alexcoven.com

Bug is only in Mobile Safari.
[image]

Mobile Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Can you please check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271460/fixed-positioning-z-index-issue-in-mobile-safari)? discuss about fixed position and z-index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was using vh as my variable for height and it was not getting read well on mobile devices. I than changed the height of my containers to be

```
height: calc (100% - 60px);
```

60px being the height of my footer. This worked famously!